# Maven + Eclipse: Adding exclusions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm configuring Maven in our software and it is working really well. I have some details to fix that aren't working as I want, and I need to know what could I do. Specifically, we all work with Eclipse and in the previous configuration -without Maven- we defined the inclusions and exclusions in the Build Path manually. So we have things like exclusions of `*/.svn/` and Include(All).

We work with the option **Project->Build Automatically** checked, so we found that Eclipse's build is not the same that Maven build. And checking the Build Path option we found that for Eclipse, the problem cames from Inclusions and Exclusions. We have a lib folder that is created under our OutputDirectory, and there are some missing files because if we do

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

the Inclusion patterns are like `*.java` and we need Include(All). So, Is there a way to define specific include/exclude options in Eclipse build path from our pom?

We have a specific source structure, so we already have plugins defined like:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-source-folders</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                     ...
```

In addition, I need to know if is deprecated configuring eclipse with

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

because I read that this plugin is under deprecation.

Edit: I'm using Maven 3.3 and Eclipse 4.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`maven-eclipse-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is discontinued and you shouldn't use it. From their homepage:

> Note: This plugin is retired. It is no longer maintained.

I have faced the very similar issues you are facing: when Maven is generating source files, Eclipse with M2Eclipse, even when explicitely adding those sources to the buildpath with the `build-helper-maven-plugin`, does not always detect those new sources and it results in build errors in Eclipse (although the Maven build is fine). I didn't find any nice way of way of tackling the problem directly.

The only workaround I found that works reasonably well is to add manually the generated sources to the buildpath of the Eclipse project by right-clicking the new source parent folder and selecting *"Build Path > Use as Source Folder"*. This fixes the buildpath problem. Having done that, it still continues to work, even after cleaning and rebuilding completely the Maven project.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't modify manually the inclusions and exclusions rule of the buildpath. In this particular case, it is the only workaround I found but note that we're just adding this specific new source folder to the buildpath. Nothing is manually excluded.

I hope that use-case will be supported consistently by the M2Eclipse plugin and its connectors in the future...